# shp file not reading

Tags: r, rgdal

Following this [website](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317988/how-do-i-plot-spatialpolygon-dataframe-layer-on-a-leaflet-map), I used the `rgal` package to read my file but it keeps giving me this error.

> Error in ogrListLayers(dsn = dsn) : Cannot open data source

Here's the code I used to open the file

```
adm<-readOGR("MP14_PLNG_AREA_WEB_PL.shp")
```

Comment: Did you try `library(rgdal)` first?

Comment: How about you first do `library(rgdal)`

Comment: I did call the library

Comment: What's the source of your shapefile?